# Strange behaviors when loading Vim color themes

Tags: themes, vim

[Here](https://gist.github.com/IthacaCow/1ace8e54c4217bc5b987) is some links and screenshots needed by this question.

I downloaded two Vim color themes: `Lettuce` and `Monokai`.  **(As seen in the link provided.)**

In my `.vimrc`, if I only have `colorscheme lettuce` and comment out `colorsheme monokai`, scheme will load incorrectly. **( as seen in screenshot 1 )**

If otherwise I only load `monokai`, it works! **( as seen in screenshot 2 )**

If I first load `monokai` then `lettuce`, `lettuce` will work! **( as seen in screenshot 3 )**

I guess in `monokai.vim` there must be some configuration that makes this situation happen.

Do anyone know why?

My Vim runs on LXTerminal on a Lubuntu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install vim by default it wouldn't come with full functionality.

type `sudo apt-get install vim`

See this SO [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074614/why-does-vi-behave-differently-in-ubuntu-than-in-centos) for more information